# Is it possible for MUST to say a situation in future

Tags: modality

The meanings of MUST of Epistemic is the speaker or author has evidence or knowledge that   warrants a particular conclusion. And the meanings of SHOULD of epistemic is a speaker or writer makes a supposition about a future situation   on the basis of knowledge or experience they possess. What's more, some argue the different between MUST and SHOULD is MUST is  stronger than epistemic should ,put differently, the speaker or writer has a    greater degree  of confidence in the conclusion they are drawing. So, if I say a situation in future I can only use SHOULD?

Comment: You could say the sun must rise every day and the weather should be getting colder as the Winter arrives. But your rules may not be correct as general rules: You must get milk tomorrow for our coffee. I am sure you should bring a dinner gift if you want to be invited again. The last 2 sentences contradict your rules, and they are ordinary.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin Hi, I think the last sentence you provided above is the meaning of obligation, which is Deontic modality

Comment: It express a conditional situation that someone would invite you again if he received a gift, which is a suggestion.